Tips for writing code that will be maintained by people who aren't familiar with good programming practices
I'm a mechanical engineer who works at a design build construction firm, and I've taught myself a lot more about coding and good programming practices since I started working just to automate some things we do (mainly VBA Excel). I'm probably still a novice in this respect compared to a full-time programmer, but I've learned a fair amount of things that made it easier for me to debug and update the programs I've worked on over the years.
However, good programming practices is not something you learn when you're studying an non-CS related engineering degree in most cases (we do learn a bit of programming though for doing things like complex math problems and simulations of physical systems), and I found that most of the code I see written by others is not following standards like those I've learned on this website and elsewhere. More importantly, I'm worried that some of the things I do to make code easier for myself to debug and maintain will actually make it harder for others to do so if they don't know about the programming best practices. For example, if you understand function calls, using lots of little functions that reference each other will be much easier to read and maintain. But if you're fuzzy on the concept of one function referencing another, it could make it harder to read the code compared to seeing the lines of code written in the order they will be run in.
Another issue is that spreadsheets we make are generally left alone for a couple of years at a time, then updates could be returned to by someone who has not seen them before (usually when the construction schedule gets slow). Overall, engineers at my company will spend ~0-4% of their time programming, and the average would probably be less than 1%, so there is a real argument for not spending too much time on learning excellent software engineering principles. As of now, we aren't doing anything too major; the largest projects we're doing are on the order of a thousand lines of code. On the other hand, I think if engineers felt more comfortable programming, I think there would be more innovation in terms of automating different parts of the job to improve productivity and accuracy over time. Even if a future automation project meant bringing in professional programmers, it would be helpful to have some people who know about what we do and can communicate and understand with the programmers, and ideally we could at least maintain the code in-house. I'm not senior enough to issue a policy change in the organization by decree, but I could probably influence standards on coding issues if I made a strong case to management and/or my co-workers.
So I have a few questions about this situation:

What are the basic programming practices that are so valuable and/or easy to learn that you think would be worth the time to learn even if you didn't spend a large portion of your time at work programming?
Are there any programming practices help make code easier to read even for unexperienced programmers? One obvious one I can think of is over-commenting the code, but if anyone can think of other things like that I'd appreciate the advice.
General advice for programming practices in this situation from experience or intuition?


The thing about VBA, unlike more current languages, is that it does what it does and you don't have 10,000s or more of libraries to extend it. (Easily anyway)
That makes documenting it easier. There just are much less tools to be concerned with the future programmer not knowing what is happening in the code.
That allows you to focus on the logic of each "Why" before the "What" and "How". Sure, these things should be part of any documention, but having to spend a lot of effort explaining where library came from and its back story can take up bandwidth. This tends to cause the logic description to take a back seat.
Focus on explaining why you broke it up into the functions and procedures the way you did. That will likely be helpful to the future maintainer.
Specifically for your questions, sanitize and validate the inputs. Always assume the End User put in something that is invalid. Code to only process what you know to be valid input data. If you do this and explain your logic, you're good.

I can't resist a jokey comparison:

I'm a programmer who works at a tech company. Over the years I've
picked up a few things about bridge building to help fix the small
suspension bridge we use to get to work in the mornings. But my
colleagues are useless and only know a few basics about stress
corrosion cracking in steel cables!
What basic long span suspension bridge maintenance principles should I
try to impart to them so that the bridge doesn't collapse in a few
years? (Please explain in less than 200 words)

I think there isn't much you can do unless you transition to being "the spreadsheet guy" They will keep adding to the bridge until it breaks and then add more ropes and duct tape. Maybe one day they will hire someone to build a new bridge.
I mean it's not like this exact things doesn't happen with dedicated programming teams in software companies.

(Senior Devs at work)

Yup. Modern civilization is held together with the digital equivalent of duct tape and chicken wire.

Ha yeah that's not too far off. To be fair though, we are talking VBA code in excel sheets, not control systems for heart surgery robots or something. I'd trust you to select a water heater for your house even if you probably shouldn't design the water heating system for a high-rise.



What are the basic programming practices that are so valuable and/or easy to learn that you think would be worth the time to learn even if you didn't spend a large portion of your time at work programming?


I think a main principle is that the vast majority of people are not competent programmers, and therefore anything more than trivial programming would probably benefit from the advice and supervision of a professional programmer.
So "learning to seek appropriate professional advice and involvement" is both a valuable lesson and hopefully easy to learn.


Are there any programming practices help make code easier to read even for unexperienced programmers? One obvious one I can think of is over-commenting the code, but if anyone can think of other things like that I'd appreciate the advice.


In general I would suggest that practices that make code readable to professionals, also help make it readable for the inexperienced. That is, there is not an opposition between what the two groups need to read the code.
Obviously you can turn code comments into a training curriculum for the syntax of that particular programming language, but unless it is exactly tailored for a specific person at a specific stage of learning the syntax, then you risk introducing endless cruft which obfuscates the essential workings of the code, as much for the inexperienced as for the professional.
Most non-professional programmers struggle with reading code not because they do not have a ready English translation of code statements, but because they lack the cognitive skills and fitness to reason mentally about what workings the code is causing (whether the operations are described with English names or stated in code syntax), or the experience to make inferences about the likely purposes of those workings in the broader context.
They also often lack a sound philosophical understanding of how computers work - deficits which would typically require books of information to be supplied and studied, not just a sprinkling of code comments.
For example, fixed-width integers (a common denominator of probably any programming language) have "overflow" behaviours (either a circular progression under operations called "addition" or "subtraction", or throwing an exception) that have no explanation whatsoever in terms of the arithmetic people are taught at school. At school, most people were taught the "number line", certainly not the "number circle".


General advice for programming practices in this situation from experience or intuition?


I think my general advice would be that if you are an able programmer then this is good for you, but don't treat the activity as something that anybody else ought to be able to do, or think that there is some sensible approach to things whereby non-programmers will be able to work effectively with the artefacts of programming, like code listings, which had to be produced in the first place by skilled programmers.
Otherwise you put yourself in the laughable position of being like a professional footballer asking how to play a professional game in a manner that a non-footballer could execute.
Even if you're also a football trainer as well as a professional, the goal of training activities is to bring others up to a professional standard, and training would occur in their own special sessions separate from your professional games. You would not seek to bring your own routine professional performance down to a level where it demonstrates no professional skill (and where, by virtue of being patently unskillful, others can more easily understand and emulate the same poor performance)!

I like the point about mentorship, and I'm trying to get better about talking to people about the programs I write so there's a bit more institutional knowledge. At least where I work, I think people I work with are smart enough to understand the concepts of the code we use, but they have a real lack of experience and familiarity with it. And they have been writing VBA code that works already, just it's usually going to be harder to maintain than would be ideal because they are doing things like not using enough function calls.

@nateAtwork, it's not just about the number of function calls, but the shape of how the overall routine is folded into callable subroutines, and the quality of the names which are assigned to those subroutines - expert judgments which your colleagues will not have enough experience to make. It's also not just whether your colleagues are smart enough in theory to grasp the concepts, but whether they will apply their time and energy to actually acquire and become proficient with them all.

Just write the best code you can write. Don’t try to be clever. The result is that developers better than you can just read it, and less good developers can learn from it.
